# cycle.js pager issues

Tags: jquery, jquery-cycle

Im trying to make a pager for my image cycling using this plugin:
http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/pager3.html

```
but even tho it looks like Im doing it right, my pager wont work. Here is my code:
    /////////////
    // This is my pager on the left side of my slideshow
    /////////////
        <ul class="imageList">
            <?php foreach ($imgs as $img) : ?>
            <li>
                <a href="#">
                    <img src="<?php echo $img[0]; ?>" height="64" width ="64" alt="<?php echo $title; ?>" />
                </a>
            </li>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </ul>
    /////////////
    /// here is the slider    
    /////////////
    <?php $imgs = get_post_images(get_the_ID(), 'full'); ?>
    <div class="imageCycler nextImage">
        <?php foreach ($imgs as $title => $img) : ?>
        <div>
            <img src = "<?php echo $img[0]; ?>" alt = "<?php echo $title; ?>" />
            <p class="imageInfo">                       
                <?php echo $img[3]; ?>                  
            <p>
        </div>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
    </div>
    /////////////
    /// here is my jquery 
    /////////////
       $(.'imageCycler').cycle({ 
            fx: 'fade', 
            speed: 300, 
            next: '.nextImage',
            prev: '.prevImage',          
            timeout: 0,
            pager: '.imageList', 
            pagerAnchorBuilder: function(idx, slide) { 
                // return selector string for existing anchor 
                return '.imageList li:eq(' + idx + ') a'; 
            } 
        });
```

This is a wordpress theme Im making so thats what all that php is, Im just pulling image attachments from a post and listing them out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My bad, looks like cycle.js has two js files, one has basic functions and the other one (the one i didnt have) contains the pager functionality.

Answer (score 0):

Main pager element in cycle is a single container per slideshow. You are creating many of them in your loop and in addition you are trying to append `LI` elements to a `P` tag which is invalid html. Take pager out of the loop and use valid html structure

Comment: the .imageCycler element is the single slideshow container and the loop is creating single divs which hold the images and the <p> tags. The slideshow works fine when I click the image or the "next" button. but its the pager thats the issue, thats the .imageList element. the loop is creating <li>s with thumbnails inside them.

Comment: you've essentially repeated what I was pointing out..your structure is incorrect

Comment: actually, those P tags are in a different element than the list items. and the loop is creating the individual images inside the main paged element in the slideshow. I figured out the problem tho, there are two different .js files and the other one had the pager functionality